# Creating a global temp table in a SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, temporary-tables

I want to create a global temp table in a SQL Server Agent Job.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE ##TestEmployee(Id int, EmployeeName nvarchar(50))
```

When I execute in SSMS, all is well.

I then put the above code on a SQL Agent Job. The job will complete successfully, but when I try doing a select statement in SSMS, I get an `Invalid Object` error.

```
SELECT * FROM ##TestEmployee
```

Are there any gotchas I am missing by creating a global temp table in SQL Server Agent?

Comment: Why are you using a global ##temp table instead of a permanent table? Where exactly are you trying to access the table, and is it after the job has finished?

Comment: I want use a global ##temp table in an SSIS package, to assist in some set based updates. Job step 1 create ##temp table if it does not exist. Job step 2 execute SSIS package. Job step 3 truncate or drop ##temp table.

Comment: You could do that with a permanent table too.

Comment: In the end a permanent table is where I'll go. I do that for some daily ETL processing. I am exploring the pros and cons of a temp instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between global and local temp tables isn't how long they exist, it's who can see them.

Local temp tables can only be seen by the session (spid) that created them.  Global temp tables can be seen by everyone, but only while the session that created them is active.

If you are running it in a SQL Agent job, as soon as it completes it disappears. That's why you can't access it, because it is no longer there.

Comment: My intent is a global ##temp table, instead of a local #temp table. I want to do a select from the ##temp table in subsequent job steps.

Comment: I see the error of my ways. I was mistaken in thinking a global ##temp table would exist beyond the life of the session that created it.

Comment: Although this is an old thread, but for those having issues with #Temp tables in Agent job. Please note, the #temp tables only live within the scope of a **Step** (NOT the lifespan of entire Job). This means if a #temp table is created in step-1, it won't be visible in step-2 of the same Agent job. I had to confine #Temp table interaction within the scope of a single step to be able to use #Temp table in one of my Agent jobs that was failing due to this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding global temporary table visibility is essential when using these objects, especially when the global temporary table is used from different sessions.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4031/sql-server-global-temporary-table-visibility/

Comment: You're not actually responding the question of the original poster. Being more concrete would help him/her better. If you just need to add a comment, *add a comment* instead of an answer.